# Link doesn't pass on the user's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A link isn't working and generates the error `Couldn't find User without an ID` referring to the controller method. I would expect for the `adduser_path(@user)` in the link below to pass the ID. I also tried `adduser_path(@user.id)` in the link but that made no difference. What is wrong with this code?

The link in a view:

```
<%= link_to "Add user", adduser_path(@user), { method: :get, role: "button", class: "btn btn-default" } %>
```

The controller method:

```
def add_user
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

In routes:

```
get 'adduser'    =>  'users#add_user'
post 'adduser'   =>  'users#post_user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, and send an hash with key `id` like following:

```
<%= link_to "Add user", adduser_path(:id => @user.id), { method: :get, role: "button", class: "btn btn-default" } %>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. However, it does generate another error message. It says `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end ...orm_for(@user),` referring to the following line in the view that it should load:
`<%= form_for(@user), :method: :post, url: adduser_path do |f| %>`. Should I also adjust this form line given the change you proposed?

Comment: You are writing `:` two times with `method` like `:method:`. Just write `method: :post`

Comment: Ah yes, of course. It should be: `<%= form_for(@user, method: :post, url: adduser_path) do |f| %>` (also had parantheses in wrong place).

Comment: Exactly. And you don't even parenthesis. They are optional. You can write `<%= form_for @user, method: :post, url: adduser_path do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your link to:

```
<%= link_to "Add user", adduser_path(@user.id), { method: :get, role: "button", class: "btn btn-default" } %>
```

And your route to

```
get 'adduser/:id'    =>  'users#add_user'
post 'adduser/:id'   =>  'users#post_user'
```

Comment: I think the routes change alone should have fixed it.

Comment: @MaxWilliams If you write say `new_user_path(@user.id)`, it will generate `/users/new.2`, but if you do `new_user_path(id: @user.id)`, it will generate `/users/new?id=2`. And even if do not define routes, you can still pass the `id`, and controller will receive it in `params`.

Comment: I would not expect `new_user_path(@user.id)` to generate `/users/new.2`